# Move the application to another workspace in XFCE

Tags: workspaces

I added new item to my xfce4-panel with right-click -> Add New Items -> Workspace Switcher.

It's properties are:
Number of rows 1
checked : Switch workspaces using the mouse wheel
unchecked : Show workspace names

Do you know how to move a few applications to another workspace? I can't figure out how to add second workspace.

Thank you

Comment: Try Ctrl+Alt+Shift+{arrow key} that might work

Comment: When I press this key combination nothing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Xfce 4 you can define multiple workspaces by either adding a new wokspace switcher to the panel, as it has been done in the question, or by using the workplace switcher that is already installed in the lower right corner by default.

With a right click on this swicher you can select the switcher properties. **Choose more than 1 row to have more than 1 workspace.**

Moving applications to another workspace can be done with a right click on the application's top title bar and select *Move to Another Workspace:*

[image]

Number and names of workspaces can be defined in the **Xfce 4 Settings Manager** (from *Applications -> Settings*):

[image]

Comment: I removed the default workspace switcher a few months ago because I thought I won't need it. When I set "number of rows" in the Properties to 2 and click Close button the value will change automatically to 1. I don't have in "Move to Another Workspace" two workspaces.

Answer (score 3):

You may also [re]define keyboard shortcuts for window management via the Settings Manager>Window Manager>Keyboard (tab).

Among them, you will find such definitions as:

- Move window to previous workspace : Alt-Ctrl-Home
- Move window to next workspace : Alt-Ctrl-End
- Move window to workspace 1 : Alt-Ctrl-Numpad-1
- etc